# Is this exercise correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

There is an exercise wich asks to: "**Write a logical sentence to follow each statement. Use the correct passive or causative form of the verbs in brackets.**

**1. We couldn´t use our washing machineall week. (repair)**". My question is wether it would be correct to answer with: "*The washing machine needs to be repaired*".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would.

You are using the verb required, your sentence is grammatically correct and it's logic is sound.

Should there be anything you're unsure about, simply ask in the comments and I shall do my best to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been given the answers to this exercise but it said that the sentence should be "The washing machine was being repaired".

Comment: Ah, in that case the sentence would additionally have to explain the original sentence, which wasn't clear through the question.

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the principles of SE EL&U. It is a mere assertion without any justification to support it. It may well be correct, but if I were to post an answer asserting the opposite, how would anyone know which of us is correct. In fact this question is off-topic for a number of reasons, but it is especially important that SE does not exist to provide a platform for dialogue between individuals but straight answers to well researched questions of general interest.

Comment: @David Thank you for pointing it out, but I fail to see how I could have provided a better answer and would appreciate your help. Could you provide me with some suggestions? Should I have answered at all?

Comment: I don't think it possible to provide an explanation of "yes", because this is a subjective answer based on one's familiarity with the language. This really tells you that the question is off-topic as being 1. subjective, 2. at the level of English Language Learners 3. Proof-reading. Many new users of the site are motivated by a desire to help others with their English, but if you read the objectives of the site, this is only at a level where a point of grammar or usage can be explained in an objective way. Often you have to find a dictionary definition or quote to keep yourself honest.

Comment: @David I understand the question not being suitable for EL&U, but I don't see the subjectivity. If the criteria for a correct answer are provided, and those criteria have been fulfilled, wouldn't that make the answer objectively correct? Is it due to the question that my answer is subjective or am I to blame?

Comment: It is the question, not you. If the answer had been incorrect you could have explained why, or if the poster had indicated a particular word etc. he was unsure of (giving an alternative) you could have explained why it was right. Try to look at some high voted questions with high voted answers to get an idea.

Comment: +1 This answer is correct and it's not subjective. There could be multiple answers to the test question, but the question asked *here* is if the answer that *was* provided to the test question is acceptable or not.